Configuring ffmpeg HLS demuxer buffering strategy
Are there options to configure the buffering strategy of ffmpeg's HLS demuxer in a scenario where I use it to pull a HLS stream as input and I re-stream that?
I am looking for options that would allow me setting the number of pre-fetched TS segments / or the prefetched duration for instance.
